# How is determined which modules are included with the Rakudo Star release

Tags: raku, rakudo-star

Rakudo Star is a release targeted towards end users (if I'm not mistaken). As such, it includes a number of useful modules that can be used in a wide range of projects.

But how does the team behind it decide which modules to include? Do module developers talk to them and ask for inclusion, or do they look at usage statistics and include the most popular? Or is inclusion completely arbitrary?

What process should one go through to get their module included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of modules is in the [`star` repository](https://github.com/rakudo/star/tree/master/modules), includes as sub-modules of the repo. I haven't seen any kind of description of what modules are installed there and why, but I guess using [the issues](https://github.com/rakudo/star/issues) and/or pull requests is the way to go. In fact [there's this closed issue](https://github.com/rakudo/star/issues/103) which points in that direction, including a reference to ecosystem statistics, so I guess regarding your three questions.

1. There's no established procedure that I have been able to see.
2. Apparently, they look at statistics, after some developer asks for them.
3. I don't think that's the case. They at least have to pass all the tests in all platforms to be included. Also, I don't think my evolutionary algorithms module will be included any time soon.